# World's Wine's Dataset

Tags: dataset

I'm conducting a machine learning project and therefore looking for a world's wine's dataset to create a classification model based on user's ratings. Can someone recommend me any datasets? Haven't found such public datasets that contain enough data and features.

Comment: You might have better luck at [OpenData.SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Are you looking for whatever dataset to build a recommendation system? Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Kaggle has a "Wine Reviews" dataset with over 130k reviews. There are even several tutorials based on this dataset I believe. I would check those notebooks before starting any new project.

https://www.kaggle.com/zynicide/wine-reviews

Answer (score 0):

Here u are a couple of websites
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/wine
https://www.kaggle.com/piyushgoyal443/red-wine-dataset